# How to improve the security in webapp

Tags: javascript, java, spring, security

#### webapp structure

[image]

#### Code I have tried

**Js login layer**

```html
<!-- /info/sign.html (Simplified code) -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Info System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
    <!-- some styles -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <el-container>
            <el-main class="main">
                <el-input v-model="account"
                          type="text"
                          class="input"
                          placeholder="Account"
                          prefix-icon="el-icon-user"
                          maxlength=10 clearable>
                </el-input><br>
                <el-input v-model="password"
                          type="password">
                </el-input><br>
                <el-button type="success" @click="sign('/info/sign-in')">login in</el-button>
                <el-button type="success" @click="sign('/info/sign-up')">login up</el-button>
                <el-switch v-model="autoSign"
                           @change="changeAutoSign()"
                           active-color="#13ce66"
                           inactive-color="#909399"
                           active-text="auto login in">
                </el-switch>
            </el-main>
        </el-container>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (localStorage.getItem("hidden-info-autoSign") == null) {
        localStorage.setItem("hidden-info-autoSign", "false");
    } else if((localStorage.getItem("hidden-info-autoSign") == "true")
           && (localStorage.getItem('hidden-info-account') != null)
           && (localStorage.getItem('hidden-info-token') != null)) {
        location.href = "user.html";
    }
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            account: "",
            password: "",
            autoSign: localStorage.getItem('hidden-info-autoSign') == "true"
        },
        methods: {
            sign(url) {
                var copyThis = this;
                if (this.account != "" && this.password != "") {
                    axios.post(url, {
                        account: copyThis.account,
                        password: copyThis.password
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data.signStatus == 100) {
                            copyThis.$message.success("success!");
                            localStorage.setItem('hidden-info-account', copyThis.account);
                            localStorage.setItem('hidden-info-token', response.data.token);
                            location.href = "user.html";
                        } else if (response.data.signStatus == 200) {
                            copyThis.$message.success("success!");
                            localStorage.setItem('hidden-info-account', copyThis.account);
                            localStorage.setItem('hidden-info-token', response.data.token);
                            location.href = "user.html";
                        } else if (response.data.signStatus == 101) {
                            copyThis.$message.error("User exists!");
                        } else if (response.data.signStatus == 201) {
                            copyThis.$message.error("User does not exist!");
                        } else if (response.data.signStatus == 202) {
                            copyThis.$message.error("Pwd error!");
                        }
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                } else {
                    this.$message.error("Please finish the form!");
                }
            },
            changeAutoSign() {
                if (localStorage.getItem('hidden-info-autoSign') == "true") {
                    localStorage.setItem("hidden-info-autoSign", "false");
                } else {
                    localStorage.setItem("hidden-info-autoSign", "true");
                }
            }
        }
    })
</script>
</html>
```

**Java controller layer**

```java
// */controller/UserController.java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    private final UserRepository repository;

    public UserController(UserRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // use response code 100~199
    @PostMapping("/info/sign-up")
    SignResponse signUp(@RequestBody User user) {
        if (repository.existsByAccount(user.getAccount())) {
            return new SignResponse(101, "");
        } else {
            user.updateToken();
            repository.save(user);
            return new SignResponse(100, user.getToken());
        }
    }

    // use response code 200~299
    @PostMapping("/info/sign-in")
    SignResponse signIn(@RequestBody User user) {
        if (!repository.existsByAccount(user.getAccount())) {
            return new SignResponse(201, "");
        }
        User realUser = repository.findByAccount(user.getAccount());
        if (realUser.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())) {
            realUser.updateToken();
            repository.save(realUser);
            return new SignResponse(200, realUser.getToken());
        } else {
            return new SignResponse(202, "");
        }
    }
}
```

I know the info display in front-end is not safe, but I have no idea to do something in back-end.

If someone wants to attack my system and get information, it will be troublesome.

#### Problem

- How to improve the security of the login section? What strategy should I use?
- Other suggestions also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should try use SSL certificate on your front-end/back-end to ensure that data transferred is not visible explicitly, is private and integral [link](https://serverguy.com/ssl/google-forcing-ssl-certificate-websites/) here.
2. Maybe you should wonder about something like Basic Authentication. It's additional information in HTTP Header with credentials. [Check this out](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication).
3. Never store passwords as plain text. Use something like BCrypt with random salt added. [Try this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt).